# Problems trying to use GroupBy with multiple properties using the LINQ Method Syntax

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I've got the following data:

```
Type (enum)   Date (DateTime)       Count (int)

Red           2014-07-27 11:00:00   1
Red           2014-07-27 10:00:00   1
Red           2014-07-27 09:00:00   1
Blue          2014-07-27 11:00:00   1
Blue          2014-07-27 10:00:00   1
Blue          2014-07-27 09:00:00   1
```

I would like to first group by the `Type` and then Sum the `Count` for every day.

My desired output would be:

```
Type (enum)   Date (DateTime)       Count (int)

Red           2014-07-27            3
Blue          2014-07-27            3
```

The following code will group by day like I want it to but I have no idea how to combine both grouping by `Type` and by `Date`:

```
_entityContext.Statistics.
.GroupBy(s => new { s.DateTime.Year, s.DateTime.Month, s.DateTime.Day})
```

I've been struggling this for a bit now and I end up with complex IGrouping structures and I'm kind of stuck now. Google steers me towards Query Syntax structures but I'm really wondering if this is possible using the Method Syntax. Last I knew Query Syntax gets translated to Method Syntax so it should be possible?

Anyone can steer me in the right direction?

**Note:**
LINQ TO Entities doesn't support accessing the 'Date' property on 'DateTime'. The exception you will get is: "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported"

Comment: one issue with your desired output is that you have the column "Date" in there.  That means that you're grouping both by the Type column and the Date column.  Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: I basically have statistics that are recorded with an hourly interval. I want to group those by Day... but, I also want them grouped by Type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `Type` to your `GroupBy`:

```
_entityContext.Statistics.GroupBy(
    // Define the key for the GroupBy to be Type and the Day
    s => new { s.Type, s.Date.Year, s.Date.Month, s.Date.Day},
    // Reduce each group to just the key and the sum of its Count values
    (key, ss) => new { key, count = ss.Sum(s => s.Count) }
);
```

Tested to work with LINQ-to-Entities.

Comment: Great use of the overload.

Comment: This is very close to what I want. Would it be possible to create "nested" groups of days within the Type? Something like Type = Red -> Day 01, 02, 03, Type = Blue -> Day 01, 02, 03. If that makes sense...

Comment: @ndsc You could chain another call to `.GroupBy(s => new {s.key.Type})` after the original `GroupBy` to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I added ToList in order to avoid the error.

```
_entityContext.Statistics
.ToList()
.GroupBy(s => new 
{
    s.Type, 
    Date = s.Date.Date
})
.Select(s=>new
{
    Type=s.Key.Type, 
    Date = s.Key.Date, 
    Count = s.Count()
});
```

I found out that EF has these [Canonical Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx). There is a method called TruncateTime which i believe, not tested, would do the trick :

```
_entityContext.Statistics
.ToList()
.GroupBy(s => new 
{
    s.Type, 
    Date = TruncateTime(s.Date)
})
.Select(s=>new
{
    Type=s.Key.Type, 
    Date = s.Key.Date, 
    Count = s.Count()
});
```

Comment: Date is a field in the db and Date.Date is the date portion of that DateTime field.

Comment: `s` has no field like `Date` it is `IEnumerable` (or `IQueryable`)

Comment: s is a row in the Statistics table. So it has a Date property which is a column on that table. What am i missing?

Comment: Ok, got you, you were not referring to the GroupBy section, but on the Select. I noticed that too afterwards.... Thanks. ;-)

Comment: Pretty sure you want `Sum` and not `Count` (though it's not clear from OP)

Comment: Well, he has named the field in his expected results as Count, so i figured he wants count. But your comment really makes sense and we should let OP decide.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not the answer. The query looks all good, but LINQ To Entities doesn't support it. The exception you get is " The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Comment: Doesn't `_entityContext.Statistics.ToList()` grab all rows from the database?

Comment: Indeed. But having no where it should be about the same. I do not know if ToString would help. I thing EF6 allows ToString.

Comment: Wouldn't `AsEnumerable` fix the L2E problem? Probably better than `ToList`

Answer (score 1):

Since some people like the query style more, here an alternative:

```
var query = from elem in _entityContext.Statistics
            group elem by new{ Type = elem.Type, Date = elem.Date.Date} into grp
            select new {Type = grp.Key.Type, Date = grp.Key.Date, Count = grp.Sum(e=>e.Count)};
```

To solve the LINQ-to-Entity problem I think you just need to query from an enumerable or list or array so for example try:

```
var query = from elem in _entityContext.Statistics.ToArray()
                group elem by new{ Type = elem.Type, Date = elem.Date.Date} into grp
                select new {Type = grp.Key.Type, Date = grp.Key.Date, Count = grp.Sum(e=>e.Count)};
```